# if index of array is not defined then define null element

Tags: python, django, list

So I have this google sheets file, I need to extract event data and create Event Model in Django. So far I have no problem getting data from API, but some of the fields in spreadsheets are empty, thus, API does not return me those fields, for example, **index 23** is complete, but in **index 24** fields are not defined. It is ok for me to enter empty data in Django models, it does not matter at all. [image]

[image]

WHAT I ACTUALLY WANT is `if array[22][1]` is empty(which it is (array[22][0] is 'May 4')) then append null value for that index. I wrote this line but it doesn't work, how do I implement this?

```
for row in range(index):
        for column in range(6):
            try:
                print(values[row][column])
            except IndexError:
                values[row][column].append('')
```

Comment: I think what you need is to use values[row].append(''). Since you don't have values[22][1] you can not append anything on it.

Comment: @cagta but there is value (may 4)

Comment: Yes but it's the value of the values[22][0] it's not related to values[22][1]. values[22] = ['May 4'] so you want to convert it to ['May 4', ' '], For that purpose you should append values[22] list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `row[column]` is missing, you want to append to `row`, not `row[column]` itself (which we've already established is missing, and will get you a `TypeError` or something).

Another option would be something like:

```
for row in values:
    if len(row) < 6:
        row.extend([''] * (6 - len(row)))
```

i.e. "for each row, if it's shorter than 6 items, add enough `''` items to make up the difference".

Comment: that [''] * (6-len(row)) thing was wery clever, thank you!